# Location to save api token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, location, direction

I'm not sure which is gonna be the best location to save API key which users generating by providing email address and password, right now I'm finding temporary direction on their machine and saving it there.

But I'm not sure if it is the best approach.

Notes:

API key has to be regenerated every 6 or 12 hours (depends).

I can't save it in the cache memory, because API endpoint which returning API key for another endpoint (which requires email and password) is rate-limited by 5 requests a day.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an express-session: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sessions

Store Session:

```
let session = require("express-session");

app.use(session({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
    }
}));
```

Use:

```
router.route("/login")
    .post(function(req, res) {

        req.session.Auth = req.body.user // => user values?
    })
```

Comment: Why would you say that better then saving it to temp dir? don't really want to add a lot of requirements, want to keep it light weight.

Comment: It's better than storing it in a directory because it scales.  Session can be shared across multiple redundant instances using a persistent storage mechanism (Redis, a database, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You could use local storage.

See https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: it's node.js app, I can do that.

Comment: I meant **I can't** do that

Comment: Well, I misread your question. This API exists only for browsers.

Comment: do u know any other solution which would work in my case?

Comment: I would probably use sessions as Rahul said. Otherwise, you could use the node implementation of local storage. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-localstorage

Comment: This answer missed the ball because the OP was asking where to store a token server-side.  However, if this were a client side app, this would be horrible advice that goes against the advice of all major identity providers.  Never put an access token in localStorage, sessionStorage, a cookie, or even in the browser's memory.  https://medium.com/@benjamin.botto/secure-access-token-storage-with-single-page-applications-part-1-9536b0021321